# Angular 2 material design Collapsible Sidenav without background overlay

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to create a sidenav which expands on hover and collapse on mouseout and shows only icons. I am using md-sidenav but I think it's not possible using md-sidenav as it Overlays background and it closes entirely on clicking outside it

```
<md-sidenav-container style="position:absolute;top:0;">
    <md-sidenav #sidenav class="sidenav">
        <md-nav-list>
            <a style="margin-left:25%">
                <img src="../Content/Images/angular2-logo-red.png" height="150" width="150"/>
            </a>
            <a md-list-item>
                <md-icon md-list-icon>Home</md-icon>
                <span md-line>Home</span>
                <span md-line class="secondary">Home</span>
            </a>
            <a md-list-item>
                <md-icon md-list-icon>list</md-icon>
                <span md-line>Categories</span>
                <span md-line class="secondary">Categories</span>
            </a>
            <a md-list-item>
                <md-icon md-list-icon>bookmark</md-icon>
                <span md-line>Tags</span>
                <span md-line class="secondary">Tags</span>
            </a>
            <a md-list-item>
                <md-icon md-list-icon>question_answer</md-icon>
                <span md-line>Questions</span>
                <span md-line class="secondary">Questions</span>
            </a>
        </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>
```

I want the same looking in 
 [this Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993774/angular-material-design-collapsible-sidenav)

How is it possible ?